# i am trying to export a function to import into another javascript page but can not figure out how to do it with exports/imports

Tags: javascript, import, export

below is my code. I just want to export the function cartUpdate() so i can import it into the index page.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
            function cartUpdate() {
                let cartNum = 0
                for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    let parsedCart = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)))
                    cartNum += parsedCart
                }

                //display number of items in cart
                const cartP = document.createElement('p')
                cartP.innerHTML = cartNum
                document.getElementById('cart-number').appendChild(cartP)
            }
            cartUpdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

The export statement is used when creating JavaScript modules to export live bindings to functions, objects, or primitive values from the module so they can be used by other programs with the import statement. Bindings that are exported can still be modified locally; when imported, although they can only be read by the importing module the value updates whenever it is updated by the exporting module.

Exported modules are in strict mode whether you declare them as such or not. The export statement cannot be used in embedded scripts.

There are two types of exports:

-Named Exports (Zero or more exports per module)
-Default Exports (One per module)

check out the Document :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export